# Asus EEE 1005HAB fan always running

Tags: 10.10, fan, acpi, eeepc

I recently installed 10.10 on an EEE 1005HAB netbook and the fan is always running pretty loud. I am not too familiar with the ACPI stuff, so I couldn't seem to get it fixed. I do remember having this problem before on other laptops and it was usually a pretty easy fix. What are some common ways to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try to install Jupiter with eee support:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/jupiter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jupiter jupiter-support-eee
```

It has support for some eee pc features

Comment: I tried that, and it didn't fix it. Now, it actually gets stuck on what seems to be full speed (pretty loud fan) instead of just moderate speed.